# Prove by inductive hypothesis (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to prove this statement  map f (map g l) = map g (map f l) 
such that f (g x) = g (f x)

I need to proof this by base case and induction case. It is possible to do a proof by base case and induction case like the following:

```
     map f (map g l) = map g (map f l)

map f (map g l) = map g (map f l)   
   Base Case:    
 L.H.S   map f.(map g []) [ ]=            
          R.H.S  map g (map f []=[]           
        map f ( map g [ ])=                    
         map g [ ] = []                  
 map f [ ] = [ ]    
   Inductive Case:     L=(x:xs)  
   Inductive Hypotheses: ∀ (f.g)
  map f (map g (xs)) =
 map g (map f (xs)))   
   L.H.S   map f (map g (x:xs))=
              map f (g (x): map g (xs))= 
(f(g (x)): map f (map g (xs))
 (f(g x)) : ((map f) . (map g)) xs=        
        map f (map g (xs)) (using the Inductive Hypotheses)              
      map g (map f (xs)))                      R.H.S
```

But I think my prove is going wrong . Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think you dropped the `(f (g x)) : ...` towards the end

Comment: You have this `(f(g x)) : ((map f) . (map g)) xs = map f (map g (xs))`, but then you don't have the `(f (g x))` element anywhere in the list on the right, so that equality doesn't hold.

Comment: I think your main hypothesis should be `f(g x) = g(f x)` for all `x`s -- if so, please edit your question adding the missing `f`

Comment: Your statement is false. Let `g = show . length` and `f = reverse`. Then `g x = g (f x)` for all lists `x`. Let `l = [[0 .. 9]]`. Now `map f (map g l) = map f ["10"] = ["01"]`, but `map g (map f l) = map g [[9, 8 .. 0]] = ["10"]`.

Comment: @Hani : melpomene has disproved your statement by providing a counter-example. As chi notes, it seems likely there is a typo in your hypothesis. If we have `f . g = g . f`, then `map (f . g) = map (g . f)`, and then, by the functor laws, `map f .  map g = map g . map f` (and you would be able to reach the same conclusion through induction on the list shape).

Comment: map f (map g l) = map g (map f l) such that f (g x) = g (f x

Comment: It's a basic property of map: `map p . map q = map (p . q)`.

Comment: @n.m. all these lines not enough? also it's not assignments !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP has indicated this is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321977/prove-by-inductive-hypothesis-haskell#comment91600513_52321977) an assignment.

Prove `map f . map g == map g . map f` provided `f . g == g . f`, where `(f . g) x = f (g x)` by definition.

The inductive data type definition:

```
data [a] = []                 -- [] is of type [a]
         | (:) a [a]          -- if x is of type a, and xs is of type [a],
                              --    then (x:xs) is of type [a]
```

Base case:

```
(map f . map g) [] = map f (map g [])    -- by definition of `.`
                   = map f []            -- by definition of map
                   = []                  -- by definition of map
                   = map g []            -- by definition of map
                   = map g (map f [])    -- by definition of map
```

*whatever* the `f` and `g` are. Base case is proven.

The Inductive case: under the Induction Hypothesis that it is true for a list `xs` of some length, prove it is true for a list `(x:xs)` with one more element in front of it:

```
(map f . map g) (x:xs) 
             = map f ( map g (x:xs) )          -- by definition of `.`
             = map f ( g x : map g xs )        -- by definition of map
             = f ( g x ) : map f ( map g xs )  -- by definition of map
             = g ( f x ) : map f ( map g xs )  -- by the condition on f,g
             = g ( f x ) : map g ( map f xs )  -- by the Induction Hypothesis
             = map g ( f x : map f xs )        -- by definition of map
             = map g ( map f (x:xs) )          -- by definition of map
```

Inductive case is proven.